# In SQL Developer, can you query the same free-text field for LIKE and NOT LIKE?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-like

Can you query the same free-text field for LIKE and NOT LIKE?
For example, if the free-text row contains

> "Patient is POSITIVE. Testing was done at XYZ Clinic."

I want to pick the word 'POSITIVE' but not when 'XYZ' is in the same field so I don't want the line above to qualify.

I'm trying the line below but it's still qualifying rows with 'XYZ'.

```
WHERE FreeTextRow like '%POSITIVE%' and FreeTextRow not like '%XYZ%'
```

Comment: post the full where clause since there might be other OR clauses causing this behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If that's so, you did something wrong. Letter case matters!

```
SQL> with test (id, text) as
  2    (select 1, 'Patient is POSITIVE. Testing was done at XYZ clinic'     from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Patient is not POSITIVE. Testing was done at ZZZ clinic' from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'Patient is POSITIVE; testing at xyz clinic'              from dual
  5    )
  6  select *
  7  from test
  8  where text like '%POSITIVE%'
  9    and text not like '%XYZ%';

        ID TEXT
---------- -------------------------------------------------------
         2 Patient is not POSITIVE. Testing was done at ZZZ clinic
         3 Patient is POSITIVE; testing at xyz clinic                --> lower case "xyz"

SQL>
```

You could apply e.g. `upper` function:

```
  8  where upper(text) like '%POSITIVE%'
  9    and upper(text) not like '%XYZ%';

        ID TEXT
---------- -------------------------------------------------------
         2 Patient is not POSITIVE. Testing was done at ZZZ clinic

SQL>
```

Or, use regular expressions with case-insensitive matching (`'i'`):

```
  8  where regexp_like(text, 'POSITIVE', 'i')
  9    and not regexp_like(text, 'XYZ', 'i');

        ID TEXT
---------- -------------------------------------------------------
         2 Patient is not POSITIVE. Testing was done at ZZZ clinic

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the full where clause for us to provide a solution.

For example, the below will return results you didn't expect

```
    WHERE FreeTextRow like '%POSITIVE%' and FreeTextRow not like '%XYZ%' OR DATE_ON='22-JAN-2019'
```

So what you need to do is the below

```
    WHERE (FreeTextRow like '%POSITIVE%' and FreeTextRow not like '%XYZ%') OR 
           (DATE_ON='22-JAN-2019' AND FreeTextRow NOT like '%POSITIVE%')
```